# Using Power BI Rest API to get datasource details

Tags: rest, datasource, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-rest-api, powerbi-gateway

I am trying to get datasource details from powerbi through this REST API endpoint
GET [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/{gatewayId}/datasources/{datasourceId}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/%7BgatewayId%7D/datasources/%7BdatasourceId%7D)

I had a few doubts - where and how to get the datasourceId?
And also when I run this api in VS Code, how do I authenticate myself as the user? How does the code get to know that my email id is running the code(as that id has access to this admin role)

I am getting Response 403 as of now, but I haven't given the proper datasource id yet